# how bind function works for functional objects in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across the following find_if function.

```
find_if (coll.begin(), coll.end(), 
             bind(logical_and<bool>(), 
                  bind(greater<int>(),_1,x), bind(less<int>(),_1,y)
                 )
         );
```

I've the doubt that how the bind(greater(),_1,x) and bind(less(),_1,y) are evaluated and returning bool values there? This will not work otherwise as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    //auto fn = std::bind(std::greater<int>(), 5, _1);
    //std::cout << fn(7) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << typeid(fn).name() << std::endl;

    auto fn1 = std::bind(std::greater<int>(),5,6);
    auto fn2 = std::bind(std::less<int>(),7,5);

    std::cout << std::bind( std::logical_and<bool>(), fn1, fn2 )(); // how this works??
    std::cout << std::logical_and<bool>()(fn1, fn2)();  // Compilation error
}
```

Really curious to know how the functors are called inside the bind function. Can someone please explain how this works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering that [`std::logical_and`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/logical_and) *evaluates* its arguments, and not calls them, the code you show will not work.

Comment: `bind` is very quirky when invoked recursively.  Please consider just using lambdas.

Comment: Still not completely understood. But from your comment I understand that bind function will call the functors internally and it's result is binded to the logical_and? not sure :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand this we'll need to 1<sup>st</sup> understand how [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Member_function_operator.28.29), binds it's arguments. Given that `g` is the result of a `bind` expression which is called with: `g(u1, u2, ... uM)`:

> - If the stored argument arg is of type `std::reference_wrapper<T>` (for example, `std::ref` or `std::cref` was used in the initial call to bind), then the argument `vn` in the `std::invoke` call above is `arg.get()` and the type `Vn` in the same call is `T&`: the stored argument is passed by reference into the invoked function object.
> - If the stored argument arg is of type `T` for which `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true` (meaning, another bind expression was passed directly into the initial call to bind), then bind performs function composition: **instead of passing the function object that the bind subexpression would return, the subexpression is invoked eagerly, and its return value is passed to the outer invokable object.** If the bind subexpression has any placeholder arguments, they are shared with the outer bind (picked out of `u1`, `u2`, ...). Specifically, the argument `vn` in the `std::invoke` call above is `arg(std::forward<Uj>(uj)...)` and the type `Vn` in the same call is `std::result_of_t<T cv &(Uj&&...)>&&` (cv qualification is the same as that of `g`).
> - If the stored argument arg is of type `T`, for which `std::is_placeholder<T>::value != 0`, meaning, a placeholder such as `std::placeholders::_1`, `_2`, `_3`, ... was used as the argument to the initial call to bind), then the argument indicated by the placeholder (`u1` for `_1`, `u2` for `_2`, etc) is passed to the invokable object: the argument `vn` in the `std::invoke` call above is `std::forward<Uj>(uj)` and the corresponding type `Vn` in the same call is `Uj&&`.
> - Otherwise, the ordinary stored argument arg is passed to the invokable object as lvalue argument: the argument `vn` in the `std::invoke` call above is simply arg and the corresponding type `Vn` is `T cv &`, where `cv` is the same cv-qualification as that of `g`.

The key is in the 2<sup>nd</sup> bullet. Because the bind expressions are invoked at binding time this works:

```
std::cout << std::bind(std::logical_and<bool>(), fn1, fn2)()
```

But because there is no `&` operator defined for bind expressions, this won't work:

```
std::cout << std::logical_and<bool>()(fn1, fn2)()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now it's clear.

Comment: @PaulVarghese I love `bind` for it's clarity and for the familiarity I have with it from back in the days of `bind_1st` and `bind_2nd`. But honestly, compilers have deffered optimization of `bind` for optimization of lambdas. This is at least true of gcc: https://youtu.be/ZlHi8txU4aQ I'm not certain where Visual Studio lands on everything, but I think the general climate says prefer lambdas to `bind`s.